# Bloomberg BEQS from RBloomberg or Rbbg

Tags: r, bloomberg

Is there any way to run Bloomberg Equity screening (EQS) from R?  There is an Excel function =BEQS() that lets me do it but can't find an R equivalent in RBloomberg/Rbbg.

Answer (score 0):

The Rbbg package does not support this, but most screenings are so simple that you can easily replicate them by requesting data and pull your screening constraints over the data.

Answer (score 0):

@AlphaDev1, I noticed that CharlesCara did a push request for BEQS which may help you work out how to tackle this.

https://github.com/johnlaing/blpwrapper/pull/2

**ADDITION**

@CharlesCara made changes to 7 procedures. @Matt O'Brien suggested I post code not link in the comments. Its not my code and this is not practical, but you can see below the code addition in github from the `blp.R` for the structure of the request:

```
### @export "beqs-definition"
beqs <- function(conn, screenName, screenType="PRIVATE", languageId="ENGLISH", Group = "", asOfDate=NULL)
### @end
{
   if(is.null(asOfDate)){
      result <- conn$beqs(screenName, screenType, languageId, Group)
   } else {
      dAsOfDate = format(asOfDate, format="%Y%m%d")
      result <- conn$beqs(screenName, screenType, languageId, Group, dAsOfDate)
   }

   return(process.result(result))
}
```

He also wrote the wrapper `java/src/org/findata/blpwrapper/BeqsDataResult.java1` which is too long at 127 lines to post here.

Answer (score 0):

This is now available in the enhanced Rblpapi package, courtesy of csrvermaak in https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/pull/100.

The below code snippet is from the examples and shows how to retrieve a global sample screen:

```
oil_eqs <- beqs("Global Oil Companies YTD Return","GLOBAL")
```

Custom screens can be retrieved by setting the screenType flag to 'PRIVATE'. The following example shows how you would retrieve a custom saved EQS screen called "Swedish Mid Caps":

```
sw_eqs <- beqs(screenName = "Swedish Mid Caps", screenType = "PRIVATE")
```